# Upgrading from EVGA GTX 660 to EVGA GTX 950 - worth it?

Tags: graphics-cards

I currently have an EVGA GTX 660 Superclocked card, but just noticed the [fancy offer to buy a GTX 950 and receive £70 in-game 'value'](http://www.geforce.co.uk/2016-free-to-play-bundle#utm_campaign=2016-free-to-play-bundle&utm_medium=banner&utm_source=gfe-billboards&cid=2016-free-to-play-bundle).

My 660 can run most of the games I throw at it at highest settings (i.e. 1920x1080 and setting everything else to its highest), without really faltering. Games like Metro: Last Light can struggle sometimes, but considering the card is three years old, I don't mind too much...

However, I need some help working out whether paying for a new card is worth it at the minute. If I buy a new card, I plan to sell the old one to make back some money, so the price point of around £150 is my limit. I've been thinking about the [EVGA SSC 950](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/evga-geforce-gtx-950-superclocked-acx-2.0-2048mb-gddr5-pci-express-graphics-card-02g-p4-2956-kr-gx-291-ea.html#free_items), because I'm happy with EVGA (unless there is another card which is **really** worth changing to).

Is the 950 a worthy upgrade after running this one for three years? Are there any cards that would be better? (I'd prefer to stay with nVidia, but I'm open to suggestions). I mean, the card runs fine at the minute and probably will for a few more years to come, but perhaps it's good to keep up with the newer tech?

FYI, the games I currently play or plan to play in the near future are:

- World of Tanks
- War Thunder
- SM's Civilisation 5
- Metro: Last Light
- GTA V (planned)
- Rust (planned)

I can't imagine the 660 would be *too* happy with GTA V at near-highest settings though? I don't mind losing some quality for FPS, but visuals are quite important!

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd recommend the Polaris or Pascal equivalents of the GTX 950 when they come out. This is the first node shrink in a long while, and they look promising.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard any news of these new cards until now. I'm a little skeptical of moving to AMD (simply because I've never had one and like nVidia), but it can't hurt to wait for the first reviews to come in, right? New die size does look promising for performance and efficiency though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hold off on the GTX 950, it is going to give you almost identical performance to what you are getting now with the GTX 660. For GTA V on your 660, you should be able to get around 60fps with a mix of medium/high settings.

If you want to stick with Nvidia, you may want to wait until later this year (late Summer or Fall) when the GTX 1060 is released. If you're willing try AMD, the Radeon 480x will be available in a few weeks and should have performance similar to a GTX 970.

Comment: I looked into the specs of the 950 a bit more and it didn't really seem to offer too much, although performance in games proved it was a bit better. Sounds like it might be good to wait for the 1060 and save my money for now. I'll look into the AMD cards a bit more though too :)

Comment: Quick thought - Do you know what the expected pricing of the 1060 is?

Comment: From what I have read, my guess is around $250. Nvidia will position it (and a lower-end GTX 1050) to compete against the 480X (and 470X). The 1060's price will probably swing a little higher or lower depending on how it fares against the 480X.